# Regex to delete lines which contain an 's' which is not part of the group 'sh'

Tags: regex, replace, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of lowercase words on separate lines, like this:

```
begin
fish
fishes
fist
shapes
shop
shops
sole
sushi
zone
```

I want to remove all words which contain an 's' which is not part of the group 'sh'. The output I am looking for is this:

```
begin
fish
shop
zone
```

Here is my regex:

```
^(?!.((?!.*(\w*s\w*)).*|\w*sh\w)).*\r
```

I replace each line that matches this regex with "".

Here is my output:

```
begin
fishes
shop
sole
sushi
zone
```

My regex appears to fails where:

- The 's' is at the beginning of a word
- The 's' is at the end of a word which does not start with 'sh'

What changes do I need to make to this regex to correct this?

Comment: Are you using a particular tool to do the filtering? It might be easier to **match** words with s not followed by h `s([^h]|$)` and then filter them *out* (rather than keeping words that do *not* have an s not followed by an h), e.g. `grep -P -v 's([^h]|$)' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the string you want from group index 1.

```
^.*?s(?!h).*$|^(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jU7iM0/3)

**Explanation:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
.*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times)
s                        's'
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  h                        'h'
)                        end of look-ahead
.*                       any character except \n (0 or more times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
|                        OR
^                        the beginning of the string
(                        group and capture to \1:
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more
                           times)
)                        end of \1
```

You could also use the below regex which uses the PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
^.*?s(?!h).*$(*SKIP)(*F)|^.+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jU7iM0/4)

Comment: My Regex engine (BBEdit 10.5.13) does not support *SKIP, but your first version works fine. If I use `^.*?s(?!h).*\r`, then all the bad lines are matched, and I can replace them with "" and end up with the filtered list that I want. Thank you.

Comment: yep, James. You could use the first for matching the bad lines. `^.*?s(?!h).*[\r\n]+`

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern to match and extract the good words

```
^(?!.*s(?!h))(.*)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/100)

or this pattern to match and remove the bad words

```
^(?=.*s(?!h))(.*)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/101)

Answer (score 1):

The regx

```
^[^s]*(sh)?[^s]*$
```

would match

```
begin
fish
shop
zone
```

for example http://regex101.com/r/mP5dW5/3

- `^`  anchors the regex at the begining of the string.
- `[^s]*`natches anything other than `s`
- `(sh)?` matches `sh` quantifies `?` makes the group optional
- `[^s]*` matches anything other than `s`
- `$` anchors the string at the end of string